# Proportionally set views inside UIStackView using multiplier - swift - programmatically

Tags: swift, constraints, uistackview

I am setting a vertical stackView which fills the entire container view.

in the container view initialiser I put this code that is aimed at setting the proportional heights of the for the arranged subviews:

```
    view1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.2).isActive = true
    view2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.6).isActive = true
    view3.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.2).isActive = true
    
    
    let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [view1, view2, view3])
    
    stackView.axis = .vertical
    
    

    addSubview(stackView)
    stackView.fillSuperview()
```

When I try to run I receive this error:

`Unable to activate constraint with anchors [...]  because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.'`

Comment: put your view1 view2 and view3 in a container and now play with them.

Comment: if you add views in stackview then apply constraint to stackview not like self.heightAnchor maybe then that's work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add arranged subviews, then activate constraints related to `stackView`.

```
let view1 = UIView()
let view2 = UIView()
let view3 = UIView()

view1.backgroundColor = .red
view2.backgroundColor = .blue
view3.backgroundColor = .green

let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [view1, view2, view3])
stackView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 100)
stackView.axis = .vertical

view1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.2).isActive = true
view2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.6).isActive = true
view3.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.2).isActive = true
```

[image]